# Java fx running on UI alternatives

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

ayt.. i have a little concern here, my question is *is Platform.runlater() the only way of getting back to the UI thread or are there any alternatives..*

-for example-

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // i do something slick here

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { // is this the only way??

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                TextField txt =new TextField(" internal server error -Re-try");
                                root.getChildren().add(txt);
                            }
                        });

        }
    }).start();;
```

i'd like to know if there are other means..thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you need another way of doing the same thing?

Comment: uhmm for versatility or versatileness. but all in all i was just curious that's all @James_D

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no other means. But you can through binding do some limited stuff to effectively change the UI from another thread without calling `PlatForm.runLater()`
Example:

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void run() {
         for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, 100);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

And then in your GUI have a progressBar say:

```
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();

bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
```

Comment: I think that the internal implementation of updateProgress, just calls Platform.runLater to ensure that the progress update occurs on the JavaFX thread so that things like binding a UI element to the progress property don't cause threading issues.  So you are correct in your first statement that Platform.runLater is the primary mechanism to run on the JavaFX application thread and other mechanisms just delegate to it.  Nice answer.