# Javafx Updating UI from a Thread without direct calling Platform.runLater

Tags: multithreading, javafx, task, ui-thread, concurrent-programming

Nowadays some says it is not suitable to use `Platform.runLater()` for updating the UI from a non-JavaFX Thread and Oracle site introduce a way with bindings for progress bar updating. Here I want to update a Label, so coded it like this:

```
Task task = new Task() {
    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            this.updateMessage("Count " + i);
            System.out.println(i);
            // Thread.sleep(10);
            i++;
        }
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(task);
lbStatus.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
t.start();
```

It works.

I want to know is it good enough or is there any other ways to consider?
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java fx running on UI alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113633/java-fx-running-on-ui-alternatives)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's quite true to say it's not "suitable" to use `Platform.runLater(...)` to update the UI from a background thread. There are certainly cases where that is the correct thing to do, as shown in the [`Task` Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). What the `javafx.concurrent` API provides is a "higher-level" interface to the functionality you commonly need when you are writing multithreaded JavaFX applications. The classes in this package are written by people with a lot of expertise in multithreaded programming, so it's likely that they have accounted for subtleties that the average programmer may not be aware of.

As an example, while it is correct that `updateMessage` eventually ends up calling `Platform.runLater(...)`, the two are not completely equivalent. If you try the same thing with a naïve call to `Platform.runLater(..)`:

```
// Don't do this! It will make the UI unresponsive:
Task task = new Task() {
    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> lblStatus.textProperty().set("Count "+i));
            i++;
        }
        return null ;
    }
};
Thread t = new Thread(task);
```

your UI will become (at least partially) unresponsive. The reason is that you're scheduling so many `Runnable`s on the FX Application thread, it doesn't have time to do its regular work (rendering UI, responding to user input, etc). The implementation of `updateMessage(...)` is carefully written to "throttle" the calls to `Platform.runLater(...)` (it basically limits them to one per frame-rendering). That code is a little tricky to implement: using the `javafx.concurrent` API as in your code example means you don't have to implement it yourself.

So changes to the UI must always be made on the FX Application Thread, and the way to schedule those changes is via `Platform.runLater(...)`. In effect you either call that directly, or call code that ends up calling it. However, some of the API methods that wrap the calls to `Platform.runLater(...)` do so in quite sophisticated ways, and when those methods provide the functionality you need, you should probably prefer those to making the calls yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes you are right. direct calls to Platform.runLater() stuck the UI. "some of the API methods that wrap the calls to Platform.runLater(...)". Do you mean methods like updateMessage() ?

Talking of this particulate code, Is this good enough or is there other ways to consider?

Comment: Yes, the `update*(...)` methods in particular throttle calls to the UI; it is basically safe to call those methods as often as you like.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488280/throttling-javafx-gui-updates

Answer (score 0):

As updateMessage() on a Task finally uses Platform.runLater() to update the messageProperty, it is no alternative to a direct runLater() in your code. So the essence is:

JavaFX is not multithreaded, any Porperty binding will only work if the property is modified in the JavaFX thread, e.g. by using Platform.runLater().

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Okay, but when we use direct platform.runlater() it cause to hang the UI completely , when we use updateMessage() with some bindings it is working fine. may be that's why oracle using bindings for their Concurrency demonstration too. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm.

The question is ...
I want to know that is this good enough or is there other ways to consider?

Comment: When does the system hang, if you call Platform.runLater() in the example above, without calling Thread.sleep() in the loop? That will hang due to: causing an overload of queued 'runLater()' tasks!

Comment: Yes without calling Thread.sleep().
When use bindings and updateMessage() it is not hanged even there are no Thread sleep inside the loop.

Comment: If you need to update some text shown in the GUI at a hight rate from other threads, I recommend using a StringProperty modified by your threads, that will be polled by a Timeline at say 60Hz to decouple the high change-rate from GUI Thread activities....

Comment: I do not understand, you mean bind a StringProperty to Label and update it ? I assume currently the code doing it. or you maned something else? if it is please give me an example . Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: I did that for a ProgressBar, showing progress of a multithreaded processing at many million operations per second... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805966/java-8-parallel-foreach-progress-indication/26814087#26814087

Comment: And finally: if the code currently works fine... no reason to change and waste time on my proposal :-D ;-)

Comment: :-D Thank you for the suggestion. You are direct accessing the platform.rulater(); I am seeking an indirect approach, anyway Thank you again for the quick response. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66284/discussion-between-lalith-jayasinghe-and-jens-peter-haack).

Comment: It's also worth looking at how `Task.updateMessage()` is implemented: [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/concurrent/Task.java)